# Using Cortana's voice

Tags: c#, speech, cortana, synthesizer

I'm actually creating a homemade assistant and the default speech synthetiser ([in c#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer(v=vs.110).aspx)) hasn't a nice voice. I would like to know if it is possible, and how, to use Cortana voice and pronunciation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see how to tune Cortana's responses via this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/skills/speech-synthesis-markup-language

And you can output text-to-speech (TTS) this way:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech/api-reference-rest/bingvoiceoutput

You can also change the Windows default voice to Cortana:
https://superuser.com/questions/1141840/how-to-enable-microsoft-eva-cortanas-voice-on-windows-10

Does this help?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, the 2 first links don't help me but i think the third will !